# Javascript: divide object date value per day

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

**Hi Everyone,**
I have this object:

```
{"2017-07-09 00:00:00":4,"2017-07-09 09:00:00":1,"2017-07-09 10:00:00":4,"2017-07-09 11:00:00":3,"2017-07-09 12:00:00":16,"2017-07-09 13:00:00":4,"2017-07-09 14:00:00":6,"2017-07-09 15:00:00":5,"2017-07-09 16:00:00":7,"2017-07-09 17:00:00":21,"2017-07-09 18:00:00":25,"2017-07-09 19:00:00":1,"2017-07-10 09:00:00":11,"2017-07-10 10:00:00":4,"2017-07-10 11:00:00":21,"2017-07-10 12:00:00":22,"2017-07-10 13:00:00":23,"2017-07-10 14:00:00":42,"2017-07-10 15:00:00":14,"2017-07-10 16:00:00":36,"2017-07-10 17:00:00":21,"2017-07-10 18:00:00":5,"2017-07-11 09:00:00":16,"2017-07-11 10:00:00":7,"2017-07-11 11:00:00":26,"2017-07-11 12:00:00":34,"2017-07-11 13:00:00":39,"2017-07-11 14:00:00":39,"2017-07-11 15:00:00":30,"2017-07-11 16:00:00":33,"2017-07-11 17:00:00":22,"2017-07-11 18:00:00":1}
```

I'm trying to divide it per day and get something like this:

First create an array for the day which is 24 hours:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]
```

And than calculate how many day is in the object above and get a value for each hours and return something like below. In the object I have 3 days, so I need to return 3 arrays for each days:

```
[4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,10,3,16,...],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,4,21,22,23,42,...]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,7,26,34,39,39,30,..]
```

For each hours which is not in the object data return 0 and for each hours that exist return the specified value on the object.
for example on the object the time starts from `"2017-07-09 00:00:00":4` and it has the value of 4 and for each hours between that and `"2017-07-09 09:00:00":1`
return 0.

**Any help appreciated. Thanks a lot for your time**

Answer (score 1):

You have first to loop into each keys of your `object`.

After that many solutions, one is to convert your keys into `Date` object and compare the hour of your `object` in a `for` loop.

And retrieve the right data by reconverting your Date obj into your obj property.

**Edit**

Access your property value without function by using `Object.keys` and `findIndex`

> I've maybe misunderstand your requirement, but you've a good example
>   of how to do ;-)

**Example of solution**

```js
var data ={"2017-07-09 00:00:00":4,"2017-07-09 09:00:00":1,"2017-07-09 10:00:00":4,"2017-07-09 11:00:00":3,"2017-07-09 12:00:00":16,"2017-07-09 13:00:00":4,"2017-07-09 14:00:00":6,"2017-07-09 15:00:00":5,"2017-07-09 16:00:00":7,"2017-07-09 17:00:00":21,"2017-07-09 18:00:00":25,"2017-07-09 19:00:00":1,"2017-07-10 09:00:00":11,"2017-07-10 10:00:00":4,"2017-07-10 11:00:00":21,"2017-07-10 12:00:00":22,"2017-07-10 13:00:00":23,"2017-07-10 14:00:00":42,"2017-07-10 15:00:00":14,"2017-07-10 16:00:00":36,"2017-07-10 17:00:00":21,"2017-07-10 18:00:00":5,"2017-07-11 09:00:00":16,"2017-07-11 10:00:00":7,"2017-07-11 11:00:00":26,"2017-07-11 12:00:00":34,"2017-07-11 13:00:00":39,"2017-07-11 14:00:00":39,"2017-07-11 15:00:00":30,"2017-07-11 16:00:00":33,"2017-07-11 17:00:00":22,"2017-07-11 18:00:00":1}

var dataKeys = Object.keys(data);

var dataKeysParsed = dataKeys.map(function(d){
   return new Date(d);
});

var res =[];
for (var i=0;i<=23;i++){
  var id = dataKeysParsed.findIndex(function(k){
     return k.getHours() == i
  });
  
  res.push(id > -1 ? data[dataKeys[id]] : 0);
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. How I can return each days on separate array as I show on the question?

Comment: Format your data object into an array of days and adapt my solution ;-) 
`data[{day1},{day2},...]` => loop into each day and apply my method.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that. Unfortunately couldn't find something in internet either :(